# Unable to connect to remote mySQL database which is running on a container on different machine

Tags: mysql, docker, networking, containers

I am trying to connect to mySQL database on a different machine. And the mysql is running on a container.

[image]

I used given bridge network ip address generated for docker container to access mysql from different machine(on same wifi network).

before that i have granted access to host IP address by running below commands in mysql console.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'172.x.x.x' IDENTIFIED BY 'root' WITH GRANT OPTION;

flush privileges;
```

also updated /etc/mysql/my.cnf file

```
bind-address   = 127.0.0.1
bind-address   = 172.x.x.x
```

when i tried to execute with `mysql -u root -h 172.17.0.1 -p` it is giving

```
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '172.x.x.x' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

Is anything i am missing?

Comment: skip-networking: prevents remote connections, also bind-address ensures that you can only connect from the same ip which is the localhost. have you tried to remove them ? or why you added them while you want to allow remote connection ?

Comment: @MostafaHussein, sorry i posted wrong info, now i updated

Comment: Use only one `bind-address` if want to make it available on both then use 0.0.0.0, i guess defining it twice is not correct

Comment: Hi, were you able to make it work by the settings in my previous comment ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the line below and remove other bind-address configuration in order to be able to receive connections from localhost and other available interfaces :

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```